# Text language translation in android

Tags: android, machine-translation

Now Google translate API is a paid service. i am trying to create a language translator app for a text input data. Basically i need to translate an English text/sentence to Hindi. Without using Google API. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can we use language libraries for translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, Microsoft has http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had checked once, but i think Microsoft Translator API not supporting some languages like Hindi. Please give me some suggestions on this.

Comment: the website `http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/`, the right area with the title `* Site language`, in the language selector list, you will find the `Hindi` language, i think may be it support.